# Convert ByteArray response from API to a File in Typescript and save it

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

There are already few questions like the one I am asking and I tried those approaches but they didn't work for me, maybe I am missing something and hence I am asking a new question.

I am calling an API in my typescript application, the API returns me an object which has a field containing the byte array representation of a file. Here's how the response model looks

```json
{
"fileName": "Pokemon.xlsx",
"fileData":"this is the byte array representation of the file",
"fileContent":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
}
```

In my typescript component I am calling the API and converting the JSON response into a response interface, this given code is what I referenced from other links

```js
this.pokemonService.getExcel(REQUEST_OBJECT).subscribe((response) => {
      if (response) {
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(response.fileData));
        const fileBlob = new Blob([bytes], { type: response.contentType });
        if (fileBlob.size > 0) {
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
          link.download = `${response.fileName}`;
          link.click();
        }
      } else {
        //show error
      }
    });
```

given is the response interface that I cast the response to

```js
export interface PokemonResponse {
  fileData: ArrayBuffer;
  fileName: string;
  contentType: string;
}
```

The issue with the above code is that when I open the excel it shows that the file is corrupted,

[image]

I also tried converting the `fileBlob` in the above code to a `File` object using the below code but still the same result, the downloaded file when opened with excel shows as corrupted.

```js
const file = new File([bytes], response.fileName, { type: response.contentType  });
```

One thing I notice is that the `ArrayBuffer` contains a string representation (base64 is what I am guessing) of the file whereas the API is returning an array of bytes.

I tried to call the API directly using a C# console application and in the console app, it works as expected, the excel file is created and I can open and view the data without any corrupt file alert.

[image]

I feel like I am close to the solution but I am missing something here with regards to `ArrayBuffer`. Please suggest.

**EDIT:** Adding screenshot of the byte comparison of C# console app vs typescript app

Console app:

[image]

and here's a presentation of the byte I get in the typescript application, note that I am printing the `bytes` variable shown in the code above which is a `Uint8Array`,

on observing both the byte representation it seems that the bytes are not in the same sequence, I think the `Uint8Array` conversion could be disturbing the sequence in typescript.

[image]

Comment: "There are already few questions like the one I am asking" - would it be possible to [edit] the question to add links to them and say what part didn't work/apply?

Comment: The code I shared in the above question is the one I tried from other links. I have edited and added the comment @AndrewMorton

Comment: If you use a hex editor to compare a file download that works ("call the API directly using a C# console application") with the file download that doesn't, does anything stand out, such as an off-by-one file length, or different bytes at the start/end?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have added the screenshot of the bytes from C# and typescript app.

Comment: That does not look good: it seems that you have discovered somewhere to investigate what causes the differences ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time I was able to resolve the issue.

I found that we have to explicitly mention the type of data the browser is supposed to parse and return, so before returning the response from the service in angular, I updated the content type with the following code

```
contentType: `data:${response.contentType};base64,`
```

Please note that `contentType` is a property of the `PokemonResponse` interface as shown above.

once I did this, the file was downloaded successfully. I assumed that this was already done by the browser but I was wrong.

For reference here's the entire code that I have to download the file

```
axios.post<YOUR_RESPONSE_INTERFACE>('YOUR_API_ENDPOINT')
    .then((response) => {
        const updatedContentType = `data:${response.data.contentType};base64,`
        const fileDownloadElement = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(fileDownloadElement);
        fileDownloadElement.download = `${response.data.fileName}`;
        fileDownloadElement.href = updatedContentType + response.data.fileData;
        fileDownloadElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        fileDownloadElement.target = '_blank';
        fileDownloadElement.click();
        document.body.removeChild(fileDownloadElement);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

I hope it helps.